# Why pop method removes two list at the same time?

Tags: python, methods, crash

I'm doing the Python Crash Course and I got to this exercise, and I was wondering why the pop method is removing two list of my guest.

```
guest = ['aaron', 'john', 'pedro', 'kevin', 'mark', 'brad']
print(guest)
guest.pop()
print(f"{guest.pop()}") 
print(guest)
```

Output:

```
['aaron', 'john', 'pedro', 'kevin', 'mark', 'brad']
mark
['aaron', 'john', 'pedro', 'kevin']
```

I tried assigning it with variable now it works. How is it different from the first though?

```
guest = ['aaron', 'john', 'pedro', 'kevin', 'mark', 'brad']
print(guest)
guest_1 = guest.pop()
print(f"{guest_1}")
print(guest)
```

Output:

```
['aaron', 'john', 'pedro', 'kevin', 'mark', 'brad']
brad
['aaron', 'john', 'pedro', 'kevin', 'mark']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`guest.pop()` removes an element from the list each time it is called.

In your first code excerpt, the first call removes `brad`, and since you don't assign it to a variable, it is effectively lost. You then call `pop()` a second time, removing `mark`, but this time you have wrapped the call in a print statement, so `mark` is returned to the f-string and printed to the console.

In your second example, you only make one call to `pop()`, store the result `brad` in a variable, then print that variable.

Comment: Oh, I thought I was just referencing the guest.pop() in print function with f string. It turns out it also called mark inside the print function.

Comment: Exactly. Please accept as answer and upvote if this helped.